# What is the function of particle に in 「Aチームに[勝つ]【かつ】チームがあるとしたら…」?

Tags: grammar, particle-に

I came across the following sentence

> Aチームに[勝つ]【かつ】チームがあるとしたら…
>   If A team is the winning team...

Why is the に particle being used in `Aチームに`?
Why would it not be `Aチームは` in this case?
I have not come across an explanation on this usage of `に`.

Comment: This is ridiculous because no one beats the [A-Team](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_A-Team).

Comment: "It's the A-Team: Bodie, Doyle, Tiger, The Jewelry Man."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, your translation of the example is not correct, but that doesn't matter with respect to what you want to know. The example means "**if there is a team that beats Team A, then...**".

The verb 勝つ has the [valency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valency_%28linguistics%29) が―に, whereby が marks the subject, and に the object:

```
 subjectが objectに 勝つ
```

The antonym of 勝つ is 負ける, which also has a が―に valency.

One famous explanation of verbs like these can be found *Shigeru Miyagawa*'s *Structure and Case Marking in Japanese* (Syntax and Semantics vol. 22).